# Bert Tokenizer add_token function not working properly

Tags: python, nlp, pytorch, bert-language-model

tokenizer add_tokens is not adding new tokens.
Here is my code:

```
  from transformers import BertTokenizer

  bert_tokenizer = BertTokenizer.from_pretrained('bert-base-uncased')

  new_tokens = []
  text = open("parsed_data.txt", "r")
  for line in text:
     for word in line.split():
        new_tokens.append(word) 

  print(len(new_tokens))      # 53966
  print(len(bert_tokenizer))  # 36369
  bert_tokenizer.add_tokens(new_tokens)
  print(len(bert_tokenizer))  # 36369
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, if a token already exists, it is skipped. By the way, after changing the tokenizer you have to also update your model. See the last line below.

```
bert_tokenizer = BertTokenizer.from_pretrained('bert-base-uncased')
tokenizer.add_tokens(my_new_tokens)

model.resize_token_embeddings(len(bert_tokenizer))
```